# Regex repeating substring

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to do a simple True/False test to see if a string matches my regular expression:

```
import re

sentence = "eee"

if sentence == r"e*":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

How can I get this to come up as True?

Comment: `print(re.match(r"e*",sentence)!=None)` or `print(re.match(r"^e*$",sentence)!=None)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import re

sentence = "eee"
matches = sentence.match("e") !== "None"

if matches:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

The `.match` method returns `"None"` if the regex does not match. The variable `matches` returns `true` or `false` according to if it is matched.